# Passing a def variable to a typed BigDecimal argument in Groovy

Tags: groovy, types

I am new to Groovy so I am a bit confused by the run time binding, typed and not typed attributes of the language. Personally I prefer types to be declared.

However, I have a question.

I have a small method that takes some variable from maps, input, whatever, that I know are numbers. Let's say that I don't know what the initial type was (it's somewhere deep in the code or comes from an external source), other that it was a number. Now I have a method that takes two of these arguments and I have to do a modulo operation on them. Because they might be decimal or not, I wrote a small method using the remainder of BigDecimal so to enforce the type I used the type BigDecimal on the method signature.

```
def callerMethod(Map map) {
    ...
    map.each{
        calledMethod(it.val1, it.val2)
        ...
    }
    ...
}

def calledMethod(BigDecimal val1, BigDecimal val2) {
    ...
    vl1.remainder(val2)
    ...
}
```

Is this correct? If the incoming argument is Integer (most of the time the primitives are boxed if I understand it correctly), will it be implicitly cast or turned into a BigDecimal?

How does this work in Groovy.

I still think that since I have the option to use types, I want to use them rather than declaring everything def. It also makes it easier to read code or see what something is if you reading already existing code

Comment: Don't declare everything as `def`... if you know the types, declare the types, especially on your public interfaces

Comment: map.each{ calledMethod(it.val1,it.val2)} doesn't make sense. Could you add to your question a sample of your input (Map?) and also an example of what the output would look like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this methods are not the type of variables, is the each of your map

In a groovy Map, the each have two signatures.
One receive a Map.Entry of parameter and other receive key and value

Ex.:

```
Map map = [key1:'value1',key2:'value2']
map.each{ Map.Entry entryMap ->
    println "The value of key: ${entryMap.key} is ${entryMap.value}"
}
```

The result of this each will be:

```
The value of key: key1 is value1
The value of key: key2 is value2
```

Or could be like this

```
Map map = [key1:'value1',key2:'value2']
map.each{ def key, def value ->
    println "The value of key: ${key} is ${value}"
}
```

And the result of this second will be the same of the first.

If you want to pass two specific arguments to you calledMethod, pass both outside of the each like this:

```
def callerMethod(Map map) {
    calledMethod(map.val1, map.val2)
}
```

I don't understand perfectly what you want.. I hope that's help you to do you code.